# Missing dll when deploying ClickOnce

Tags: reference, dependencies, clickonce, publish

When I publish a ClickOnce application, one of the references that is included in one of my projects is missing.

If I go to my project's Properties -> Application Files, this missing reference is not even listed here.

My bin/Release folder has an .exe.manifest file, and I noticed it that it is also missing from here.

However, when I build the project, the DLL is in fact copied to my bin/Release folder.

How can I ensure it also deploys this required dependency?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution for this problem and I hope it will solve your problem to.
In my case, I'm editing an old application at work which have multiple projects, but the main project and it's back end project are the most important here.
The back end is added in the References section of the main project.
In the back end, a third party dll was imported, but this dll requires 2 other dlls.
So those 3 dlls were added in the References section of the back end project.

At that point, one of the 2 other dlls was not showing in the Application Files section for ClickOnce.
I've come up with a couple of ways of fixing it, but the most elegant one was to add this dll in the Reference section of the main project.

Comment: Sadly I also found this the simplest solution.  It bothers me because I have a growing number of applications that I need to keep up to date with all kinds of dependencies that the solution already knows about :/

Comment: Note that this will only work for COM/.NET assemblies and not for ordinary C DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [How to: Specify Which Files Are Published by ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx), change the Copy Local property value on the reference to True.

> References to assemblies (.dll files) are designated as follows when you add the reference: If Copy Local is False, it is marked by default as a prerequisite assembly (Prerequisite (Auto)) that must be present in the GAC before the application is installed. If Copy Local is True, the assembly is marked by default as an application assembly (Include (Auto)) and will be copied into the application folder at installation. A COM reference will appear in the Application Files dialog box (as an .ocx file) only if its Isolated property is set to True. By default, it will be included.

Comment: Yes I have already looked at the properties, and the 'Copy Local' property is already set to True for this DLL, in every project that it appears.

Comment: Do you have a reference to it in the ClickOnce application's project? Is that reference's Copy Local property set to true?

Comment: The application project itself does not have a reference to it. Even if I add a reference to it with Copy Local to true, it does not make a difference and the dll is still missing from Application Files nor is it  deployed.

Comment: Did you rebuild after adding the reference and then look in the application files?

Comment: I just performed a rebuild and it is still missing from application files.

Comment: Are you selecting the "Show All Files" checkbox in the Application Files dialog?

Comment: Yes I had also selected Show All Files and it is still missing

Comment: Are you referencing the assembly from the GAC?

Comment: The only thing that seems to deploy the missing dll is to add it as a file in the project itself, and set its 'build action' to 'content' and the 'copy to output directory' property to 'copy if newer'. Of course I shouldn't have to do this and then I also receive warnings because of this.

Comment: How do I know if I am referencing it from the GAC? When I add the reference, I go to Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Framework and when I search for it in the Search Assemblies field, it finds my assembly.

Comment: From your description, you are adding a .Net Framework assembly. In this case, there is no need to copy it locally and deploy it, as you are guaranteed that the assembly will be present if the application meets the prerequisite of having the required version of the .Net Framework. You just mark the required version of .Net as a prerequisite.

Comment: The strange thing is when a coworker deploys from his machine, this particular DLL is deployed.

Comment: Hi @lost_bits1110 could you tell us how do you solved this problema ?  We are in the same place as you wear.

Comment: I could not solve the problem. When upgrading to Visual Studio 2012, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I know is this an old question, but for anybody having similar issues. I think this is a cleaner way around the problem.
I had a similar issue and everything I did to get ClickOnce to deploy with the offending .dll failed.
Eventually, I had to deploy manually.
[See walk-through here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-manually-deploying-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2015)
That worked for perfectly for me. But, for the life of me, I still wonder why that process can't be added to VS (I'm using 2017 community).

Comment: Here is the link for vs2022:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-manually-deploying-a-clickonce-app-no-re-signing-required?view=vs-2022